# How to create an access database to be used by runtime

Tags: ms-access-2010

How do you save a database in Access 2010 so that the database can be connected to and the queries run from a machine that does not have Access installed? I have read that I can use runtime but can't find how to actually make it so that it can be used in runtime. Is this what the Package Solution Wizard is for or is just a certain file extension? If I do that, will the user have to install it? On my network I am not sure if that is allowed. Can you just email it as a file that doesn't need to be installed? I am really struggling to find much info.

Comment: User will need Access runtime installed if you want them to open the database and run queries from it - we can't help with your network installation issue..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make any special preparations in your database for launching under runtime. Launching Microsoft Access with your database is similar to the way you would do so with the regular version of Access. Simply launch the msaccess.exe followed by the name of your database.
You can read more about this for instance [here.](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/runtime/index.htm)

Access runtime should be installed on PC first

Comment: One important thing is that a startup form is needed, because the navigation bar isn't available to open objects. @kit

Comment: Can you access the queries via vba from excel?